# ¿Cómo usar la biblioteca Zepto desde navegadores antiguos hasta los actuales?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zepto

Desde hace poco me he valido de muchas formas con tal de sacar mejor partido a las bondades de **Zepto**, aunque para navegadores antiguos tuve que usar *jQuery 1.12.0*. Mi problema es que tenia que usar plugins y/o crear main.js para cada una de ellas, por tanto; *eso ya no me gusta*.

Lo hacía de esta forma:

```
document.write( '\u003Cscript src=js/' + ( !!global.HTMLCanvasElement && !!document.querySelectorAll && !!global.addEventListener ? 'zepto' : 'jquery' ) + '.min.js>\u003C/script>' );
```

Entonces, **¿cómo hacer posible usar solo Zepto para todos los navegadores incluyendo antiguos?**

Answer (score 1):

Me pasé 4 días para lograr lo que no parecía.
`Zepto 1.1.6 y jQuery v3.x` **ya podemos** usar para cualquier navegador antiguo, siempre y cuando dicho navegador acepte elementos básicos de HTML5.

Si no fuera menos, también podemos programar en javascript usando el estándar **ECMAScript versión 5/6**, al estilo `( Vanilla JS )` o Plain JS.

Los requisitos son:

```
"navegadores": {
    "chrome": "1+",
    "firefox": "3+",
    "ie": "6+",
    "opera": "7+",
    "safari": "4+",
    "ios_saf": "3+",
    "ios_chr": "?",
    "android": "1+",
    "op_mob": "6+",
    "ie_mob": "6+",
    "firefox_mob": "1+",
    "bb": "5+"
}
```

> Se demuestra en [SisePuede v0.4.1](https://github.com/Webnewbies/SisePuede) GitHub Repos.